# Understanding classes, inheritance and super()

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes, runtime-error, subclass

I'm trying to learn how to better use classes but super() is really throwing me for a loop. Why isn't super() searching through the properties class to find the attribute "foo"? In my mind this should be printing the number 10 but clearly its not and I have no clue where I am missing some understanding. I am running python 3x (I mention this since I know super() behaves differently in 2x). I have tried just using `super()__init__()`, I have tried not putting the `super()` call in the properties class.

```
    class properties:
        def __init__(self):
            super(properties, self).__init__()
            self.foo = 10
    
    class losses(properties):
        def __init__(self):
            super(losses, self).__init__()
            self.bar = 5
             
        def foobar(self):
            print(super().foo + self.bar)
    
    test = losses()
    test.foobar()
```

No matter what the output is always:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

Comment: `super` searches *the class and the classes in the method resolution order*. You just want `print(self.foo + self.bar)` because you want an *instance attribute*

Comment: Also since `properties` class does not have any superclass; `super(properties, self).__init__()` is not required. Also the syntax changed in Python 3.0: you can just use `super().__init__()` instead of `super(Child, self).__init__()` .

Comment: Ah thank you that makes a lot of sense. Say I had another attribute called `foo` in the `losses` class, would it be possible to call the `foo` in the `properties` class or would that just be poor coding practice and should be avoided in general?

Comment: @K450 not exactly. It *does* have a superclass, every class has a superclass. But more importantly, this pattern is totally acceptable if you are designing your classes for cooperative multiple inheritance

Comment: @shirtless_llama again, **those properties don't belong to the classes at all** they are *instance attributes*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga well yes; `object` class. I was just saying it in the context of user defined classes and single inheritance as provided in example, that it was not needed and the syntax can be simplified.

Comment: @K450 yes, and I'm explaining to you that it *may be* depending on how these classes are meant to be used (e.g., meant to be inherited in a cooperative fashion) again, this would be a common pattern, see [Super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, its just that I didn't treat it as MRE (which I should have and it clearly is; my bad).